# JTable doesn't show the newly inserted row/data

Tags: java, oracle, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a JTable and I populte the table as follows:

```
jTable_Std_info.setModel(DBControler.getALLStudents());
```

And the following is a static method in a class named DBControler which retrieves all the data from the database(Oracle).

```
public static DefaultTableModel getALLStudents() throws SQLException, Exception {

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    Vector rows = new Vector();
    Vector columns = new Vector();

    try {
        conn = geConnection();
        cst = conn.prepareCall("{? = call std_getInfoFunc}");
        cst.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cst.execute();
        res = (ResultSet) cst.getObject(1);
        System.out.print(res);
        ResultSetMetaData rsm = res.getMetaData();

        for (int i = 1; i <= rsm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            columns.addElement(rsm.getColumnName(i));
        }

        int row = 0;
        while (res.next()) {
            Vector vRow = new Vector(); //to store the current row
            //System.out.println("Row " +row+"\n");
            for (int i = 1; i <= rsm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String columnValue = res.getString(i);
                vRow.addElement(columnValue);
            }
            row += 1;
            rows.addElement(vRow);
        }
        tableModel.setDataVector(rows, columns);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        res.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    return tableModel;
}
```

So far everything works fine, but the problem is that if I insert a new record in the database, the JTable doesn't get the newly inserted row/data. Why is that and how can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**
It's retrieving the data when I commit my new insertion. So do I have to commit each time I update? Or is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: According to your implementation, you're going to need to create a new table model every time you add a row in the database. After you add a row in the database are you calling `getALLStudents()` again?

Comment: I am a beginner in java so I don't know much function in Java. Is there any other way that I can just update the row rather than creating a new table model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you looking for Oracle Built-In [Database Change Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/dbchgnf.htm), not sure if is accesible for Oracle's in free-versions, if not then never mind, for MySQL is there two or three similair API for Java JDBC

Answer (score 3):

> But the problem is that if I insert a new record in the database, the JTable doesn't get the newly inserted row/data. Why is that?

The TableModel doesn't know when the database is updated.

> and how can I fix this problem?

If your application is adding the row to the database then it also needs to add a row to the TableModel at the same time.

Comment: I am a beginner,and Sorry if my guess is wrong. In my code I used "while(res.next())" loop. So the program is gonna check and add rows until there is no more row. if it right, so it automatically add the new row as well isn't it?

Comment: That will work but it means you need to recreate the TableModel and read all the data from the database every time you add a single row.

Comment: Will recreating the TableModel affect the performance of the application? still even if I recreate the table model, it does not getting the newly created row. It suppose to get the newly created row, but it is not retrieving it.